# border-width value doesn't change

Tags: html, css

I am new in learning html and currently got stuck on border topic. I am trying to set border-width in html but it doesn't work. This is what I am trying to do:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <title></title>
     <style type="text/css">
         p.one {
         border-width: 10px;}
     </style>
   </head>
   <body>
     <p class="one">Hello</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

After opening html file in Google Chrome this is result that I get:

[Google Chrome result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgySH.png)

It shows that border-width is still set to 0px even though it received the value. If I try to change anything else like padding or font-size everything else works fine.

Please help I tried to search if anyone else the same problem but couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add `border-style`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        p.one {
        border-width: 10px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:red;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="one">Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add border-style.

```
p.one {
   border-width: 10px;
   border-style: solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does work all you have to do is give it a color and style

```css
    p.one {
      color : green;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 5px;
        }
```

```html
    <p class="one">Hello</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, you didn't mentioned the border other property. like **border-style**, change the color according to yours. It works fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        p.one {
        border-width: 10px;border-color:black;border-style:solid;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="one">Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```